# What XML comment tags are supported in the Object Browser

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xml-comments, objectbrowser

I'd like to provide a higher level of detail at the class level (in this case actually a `Module`) with code samples, etc., but I'm having trouble getting various tags to work.

```
''' <summary>
''' Here's a summary of <c>SmallCodeChunk</c>
''' </summary>
''' <example>
'''   Mmm, Skynet?
'''   <code>
'''      code.CodingItself("that's so meta!")
'''   </code>
''' </example>
''' <remarks>
'''   <para>Unit testable by replacing the <see cref="Implementation"/> property 
'''         with a mocked/stubbed <see cref="IThingy"/>.
'''   </para>
'''   <para>Paragraph of a bunch of stuff. <c>Y</c> is used for <c>True</c> just
'''         for the sake of making the universe a (not) better place.
'''   </para>
''' </remarks>
```

I realize that some of the tags used (like `<exception>`) probably aren't really valid, but it seems like I should be able to do things like `<example>`. And I'd expect some sort of formatting (monospace font maybe?) for `<c>` tags.

If I'm not doing anything wrong, is there a subset of XML doc tags that are supported for  display in the Object Browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [a 2009 article in MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx):

> Object Browser displays <kbd>summary</kbd>, <kbd>param</kbd>, <kbd>return</kbd>, <kbd>remarks</kbd>, <kbd>typeparam</kbd>, and <kbd>exception</kbd> comments when they exist.

A [2006 post on the MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/12/c-xml-documentation-comments-faq.aspx) adds <kbd>see</kbd> and <kbd>seealso</kbd> to that list.

Comment: Thanks, but very interesting that a post from 2006 can add something to a list of 2009, I expect that it's the other way round :).

Comment: @Sebastian: The 2009 article simply missed a couple of tags from the 2006 blog post. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of the "recommended" tags to use: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172653(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172653%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

In short they are:

```
<c>
<code>
<example>
<exception> *
<include> *
<list>
<para>
<param> *
<paramref>
<permission> *
<remarks>
<returns>
<see> *
<seealso> *
<summary>
<typeparam> *
<value>
```

where **'*'** denotes tags for which the compiler verifies syntax.
And here is a short article with some additional how to's and examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx

Comment: Doesn't quite answer my question of which of tags are valid and respected with in Visual Studio 2010's Object Browser.